# Question about possessives

Tags: british-english, possessives

Why is not it possible to write "company files" as "company's files"?

I am not quite sure whether it is correct to say "company's files".

Comment: "Company files" already implies that the company is the owner.  If the situation is unambiguous, the possessive is unneeded.  An exception might be a confusing situation where you need to distinguish between files you own that are **about** companies and files **owned by** companies.  In that case, you would need the possessive for clarity.

Answer (score -1):

I think in this case company is being used to modify files like an adjective instead of a possessive. For example: Office printer (not office's printer) or the village church (not village's church)

Examples:
https://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/en/english-grammar/adjectives/noun-modifiers

Comment: We're looking for long answers that provide some explanation and context. Please explain why your answer is right, ideally with citations. Answers that don't include explanations may be removed.